# AngularJS: Access `$scope` values after $routeProvider finished request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

How can I call/access Controller method ($scope.some_function()) after finished Ajax request!

```
var app = angular.module('home', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('IModalCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.will_call_this = function() {
        //
    };
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
            .when('/news/:cat/:slug/:id', {
                templateUrl: function (attr) {
                    return '/news/' + attr.cat + '/' + attr.slug + '/' + attr.id + '?ajax=1'
                },
                controller: 'IModalCtrl'
                // IS ANY PROPERTY/METHOD HERE
                // WHICH WILL ALLOW/ACCESS TO CONTROLLER PROPERTY
            })
            .otherwise('/');
    }]);
```

In above, I want to call `IModalCtrl`'s `$scope.will_call_this()` function after `$routeProvider` has finished the request. Just like jQuery ajax work.

jQuery Ajax e.g:

```
jQuery.ajax("example.php")
    .done(function () {
        alert("success");
        // Need this functionality in AngulaJS
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    })
    .always(function () {
        alert("complete");
    });
```

Comment: What controller are you calling the ajax from? If you want that ajax to be called after that route is finished, why not just include the call in your IModalCtrls

Comment: How will you show me an example?

Comment: `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the following.

```
app.controller('IModalCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.will_call_this = function() {
        //
    };

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, next, current) {
        $scope.will_call_this();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, but where do I found `$rootScope` variable! Should I use dependency injection?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add '$rootScope' dependency in the controller.Please check the edited answer.